# cannot reference from static context error in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I type the below code, following android development tutorial. But I got an wrong message of "cannot reference from static context error" in " new ImageDeatilFragment();"
But in Eclipse, I can create an instance in a static method.

```
 public class ImageDetailFragment extends Fragment{
        private static final String IMAGE_DATA_EXTRA  = "resId";
        private int mImageNum;
        private ImageView mImageView;
        public static ImageDetailFragment newInstance (int imageNum){
            final ImageDetailFragment f = new ImageDetailFragment();
            final Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(IMAGE_DATA_EXTRA,imageNum);
            f.setArguments(args);
            return f;
        }
    }
```

Comment: One problem I see is that you cannot reference the non-static variable `mImageNum` in the static method `newInstance`.

Comment: Mike is right. If ImageDetailFragment is an inner class, method inside ImageDetailFragment cannot be declared static. And simple solution is, like what Mike suggested, move it to own class file, or move the class parallel to your public class.